# Accessing Controller Variables in View

Tags: ember.js

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/ptmoy2/9RRfJ/

I'm using Ember 1.4 in my app.  I can display the controller variables in the view's template, but I can't access the same variable from the view.  It comes out as 'undefined' when tried outputing to console.

```
 console.log(this.get('dummy'));
```

I haven't defined a backing model because I don't really need anything persisted in this particular route.

How do I access controller variables from an associated view?

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.get('controller.dummy')`